# How to export a numpy array as an OVF file

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to export a numpy array as an OVF file. I am trying with OVF library, as following:

```
outfile = ovf.OVFFile('data.ovf', title='Data', description='My data')
outfile.add_data(resultado, name='Data')
outfile.close()
```

where "resultado"  is my numpy array, It has the following shape: data(shape) = (3, 1, 152, 304).
I am getting the following message:
AttributeError: module 'ovf' has no attribute 'OVFFile'
If somebody can help me to overcome this problem, I will really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The documentation reports that you should call `ovf.ovf_file` and not `OVFFile`. Where did you find such method name?

Comment: Hi, @Fra93. Also changing the method, I am obtaining the same error: AttributeError: module 'ovf' has no attribute 'ovf_file'... I have installed ovf 0.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Did you install with pip? I have seen such issues in a conda environment. If you're not sure, maybe try:

```
pip uninstall ovf
conda install ovf
```

•
•
•

You need to initialize a segment first. Also, title and description are not valid keyword arguments. The following works for me:

```
import numpy as np
from ovf import ovf
resultado = np.zeros((3, 1, 152, 304), dtype='f')
with ovf.ovf_file('data.ovf') as outfile:
    segment = ovf.ovf_segment(n_cells=[3, 1, 152])
    outfile.write_segment(segment, resultado)
```

Comment: Hi @yukako, I am facing problems calling ovf, receiving the following error message: FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Charlie\anaconda3\envs\spirit\Lib\site-packages\ovf\ovf.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax. Maybe it is a problem of anaconda.

Comment: Yes, @yukako. The problem in that case is that ovf is not available from current channels. For that reason, I installed with pip.

Comment: When using anaconda try conda install instead of pip

Comment: Hi, @Fra93. I think, I didn't explain well. I tried to install ovf with conda, but I have the following error message: "ovf is not available from current channels". For that reason, I installed with pip.